# How do you remove the last (empty) line in Geany?

Tags: geany

I have a project which keeps complaining about the trailing line [Geany](https://www.geany.org) adds to every file I create. It's in everything: html, js, json, python. At first it was cute and endearing. Now it's just flat-out annoying.

Background: I'm writing a Mozilla extension and it won't load the manifest file or the js file because there's an empty line at the end of each file. Finally had to open it in Notepad++.

Comment: I'm writing a Mozilla extension and it won't load the manifest file or the js file because there's an empty line at the end of each file. Finally had to open it in Notepad++.

Answer (score 4):

> How do you remove the last (empty) line in Geany?

You will likely want to open *Edit* → *Preferences* ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and under *Files* → *Saving Files* uncheck `Ensure new line at file end`:

[image: Geany Preferences]